# Can Bluemix Cloudant synch api have a field to store image?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

I have a mobile app that uses Mobilefirst Cloudant sdk to work on top of Bluemix.
One type of the json document in the Cloudant DB needs to have an image as a field. Can you give me some example in Swift as how to store and read it? 
I have a Cloudant local datastore on the device, it is synched with the server. So I shouldnot need to worry about the performance?

Thanks.

Jen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [CDTDatastore](https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore), you should use the attachment's API which is designed to hold binary blobs, such as images, see [using attachments](https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore/blob/master/doc/crud.md#using-attachments) in the CDTDatastore documentation. You should also read up about attachments and their possible performance implications in the [Cloudant Documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/attachments.html)